# How to recover JMS inbound-gateway containers on Active MQ server failure when number of retry is changed to limited

Tags: spring-batch, spring-integration

JMS Inbound gateway is used for request processing at worker side. CustomMessageListenerContainer class is configured to impose back off max attempts as limited.
In some scenarios when active MQ server is not responding before max attempts limit reached container is being stopped with below message.
"Stopping container for destination 'senExtractWorkerInGateway': back-off policy does not allow for further attempts."

Wondering is there any configuration available to recover these containers once the Active MQ is back available.
sample configuration is given below.

```
<int-jms:inbound-gateway
    id="senExtractWorkerInGateway" 
    container-class="com.test.batch.worker.CustomMessageListenerContainer"
    connection-factory="jmsConnectionFactory"
    correlation-key="JMSCorrelationID"
    request-channel="senExtractProcessingWorkerRequestChannel"
    request-destination-name="senExtractRequestQueue" 
    reply-channel="senExtractProcessingWorkerReplyChannel"
    default-reply-queue-name="senExtractReplyQueue"
    auto-startup="false"
    concurrent-consumers="25"
    max-concurrent-consumers="25"
    reply-timeout="1200000" 
    receive-timeout="1200000"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably can emit some `ApplicationEvent` from the `applyBackOffTime()` of your `CustomMessageListenerContainer` when the `super` call returns `false`. This way you would know that something is wrong with ActiveMQ connection. At this moment you also need to `stop()` your `senExtractWorkerInGateway` - just autowire it into some controlling service as a `Lifecycle`. When you done fixing the connection problem, you just need to start this `senExtractWorkerInGateway` back. That `CustomMessageListenerContainer` is going to be started automatically.